# Not able to connect to the express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am trying to connect to the express server in which I was able to connect earlier but now am no longer able to connect getting this error

> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your
> MongoDB Atlas cluster.

One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

> ```
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807:32)
> at D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
> at D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at promiseOrCallback (D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1181:10)
>
> at Mongoose.connect (D:\development_work\study\MERN_stack\mern_project\practical\travelogger\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:20)
> at file:///D:/development_work/study/MERN_stack/mern_project/practical/travelogger/server/index.js:22:3
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 0) {   reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
> servers: Map(3) {
>   'cluster0-shard-00-00.ksifo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
>   'cluster0-shard-00-01.ksifo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
>   'cluster0-shard-00-02.ksifo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
> },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> setName: 'atlas-w2uj2r-shard-0',
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined   },   code: undefined }
> ```

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.js"

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/users",userRouter); //http://localhost:5000/users/signup

const MONGODB_URL = "mongodb+srv://alish:<removedThePassword>@cluster0.ksifo.mongodb.net/tour_db?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

const port  = 5000;

mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`server running on port ${port}`)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`${port} did not connect`)
    })
```

Comment: Did you confirm what the error message asked to?

Comment: @AlexBlex, It was suggesting that it is happening because of ip address, so went back to mongodb and re-entered fresh ip address and my problem was resolved.

Comment: Please upvote question and answer, if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue it was written in the few first line of the error message, that is "*MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP*"
So, **I went back to my mongodb database and re-entered current ip address and problem was resolved**.